# Can I fix the VS Debugger trying to connect to unconnected mapped drive

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

When I have an unconnected mapped drive, the VSTS 2008 SP1 IDE debugger takes about 10 seconds to regain control.

Needless to say single stepping is painful. Is there some setting to make this go away?

I am debugging a mixed( C# / C++ / Web services ) program.

More details:

The program does not use the mapped drive at all.

I use the mapped drive only to connect to the server while I am at the office.
It is mapped as \\192.168.0.3\sharename -> f:  No DNS server involved.

It's just a pain to map/remap just to debug, when I am at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried establishing the connection via explorer first?

Also, do you need to use a mapped drive? is there any reason you cant use UNC?

You can use

```
NET USE \\server\share /User:MeMe
```

to establish a connection to the resource without actually assigning it a drive letter.

Make it a batch file and run at login.